# Why we have access to A class methods only.Why overriding methods cannot be more restrictive?

Tags: java, oop

```
class A{
    public void m1(){}
    public void m2(){}
}

class B{
    public void m3(){}
    public void m1(){}

    public static void main(String args[]){
        A a=new B();
        a.m1();

        //Why we have access to A class methods only.
        // Why overriding methods cannot be more restrictive 
    }
}
```

Comment: `A` has no fields and it's generally considered poor design to allow access to class fields.  You can restrict extension by either making the class `final` or the method `final`...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is clearly a homework copy-paste with no effort by the OP.

Comment: Does Class B extend Class A??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`B` "is A" `A`, so you can pass a `B` to a method like `doSomethingToA(A a)`. The method rightly expects to be able to see `m1` and `m2`.

You only have access to `A` methods because the type of a is `A` - it could be an `A` and not a `B`, so you can only call the methods the variables class exposes. You coulkd change main to be `B a=new B();` and now you can call B methods.

Answer (score 0):

a is defined as type A, so a.m1(), uses the method m1() from A.

You can extend A with B, and then your code will call m1 from B.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding can be possible when you extend a class or implement an interface.
i.e., overriding can be applicable when we talk about Interfaces and Inheritance.

In your code you are redefining the method that is not overriding.

Only inherited methods may be overridden, and remember that private
methods are not inherited.